# How can I connect to a server using the Visual Studio remote debugger?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, remote-debugging, visual-studio-2019

I'm following [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-aspnet-on-a-remote-iis-7-5-computer?view=vs-2019#BKMK_msvsmon) and I have the Visual Studio remote debugger app running on the target server, but I can't connect to it from Visual Studio - when I enter the URL of the server into the "connection target" in the attach to process dialog and click "find..." then the server is not found. Does the server need to be on the same LAN or something? How can I connect to this remote server? I also tried the machine name but I guess I'd need to qualify it with a domain somehow since I'm not on the same LAN as the server?

Comment: Hi ekolis, any update for this issue? If it still blocks you, please feel free to let us know :)

Comment: No, I never did get it figured out, but thanks for asking!

Comment: Maybe the reason why I succeed to do this by Internet is that my local machine and remote one use same VPN. But I have no other machines to test what's the result if the connection is pure Internet.Hope this info makes some help.  And If there's any update for this, feel free to share here :)

Comment: Yeah, I am on a VPN, but the server I'm trying to connect to is on a different network, if I'm not mistaken. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I'm trying to involve someone experienced in this topic to research this situation, it may take some time :) And I'll be back if there's any update.

Answer (score 2):

> Does the server need to be on the same LAN or something? How can I
>   connect to this remote server?

It's recommended to debug between two computers that are connected over a network, workgroup, or homegroup, or else connected directly through an Ethernet cable. And not recommended to connect over Internet though it's possible.(See [Remote debug over Internet with VS](https://keyoti.com/blog/remote-debug-net-applications-over-the-internet-with-visual-studio/))

> when I enter the URL of the server into the "connection target" in the
>   attach to process dialog and click "find..." then the server is not
>   found.

For me, I encounter similar issues when the local and remote machines are not in same domain. Here's some tips which may help:

1.Make sure the remote debugger in your remote machine has started. (waiting for new connection status...)

[image]

2.To avoid any connection issue, I suggest you can test if your local machine(VS installed) can connect to the remote machine by `Remote Desktop Connection` before attaching to process.

[image]

3.After #1 and #2, now go to `Attach to process` dialog. I suggest you type the `IPV4 address` in `Connection Target`. I tried `Machine name` several times but no luck, it only works when I use the `IPV4 address` of my remote machine. (The IPV4 address is the address we use to connect remote desktop in #2)

For me, I type IPV4 address(xx.xx.xx.xx) in the `Connection Target`, and then press **Enter**. The processes running in remote machine will then display. (Press **Enter** instead of clicking the **Find** button, and sometimes you may need to add the port, so you can also try `xx.xx.xx.xx:4024`)

**Update:**

I suggest we test the connection(local machine and remote machine) in #2 before attach to process in #3, normally we type the IP address like this:

[image]

Connect to remote machine and then start the debugger there(#1), now in #3, type the same IP address(11.1xx.1xx.1x) into the connection target. press **Enter** to pass the Windows Security popup.

[image]

Two possible reasons why you can't connect to the remote debugger:

1. You can't connect to the remote machine even by remote desktop connection in #2.
2. Your local PC(windows) can connect to remote machine(windows 2012 or...), but you forget to [start the debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-aspnet-on-a-remote-iis-7-5-computer?view=vs-2019#BKMK_setup) in remote machine. Make sure you have a window like #1 in your remote machine.

Comment: I used the IP address of the server and opened up port 4024 in the server's firewall, but I now get this error: https://i.imgur.com/CqFPvq0.png

Comment: Well, when I say "IP address of the server" I mean "the IP address that 'ping mysite.whatever.com' returns" - entering this IP address into my browser does not actually bring up the site! Is it possible to set a server to only respond to requests through its hostname and not through its IP address, or am I getting the wrong IP address from ping somehow?

Comment: I have a remote server which I can't access until I connect one specific VPN in local machine, once I turned off the vpn, I meet the same issue like your first comment. That's why I suggest we test the connection in #2 before attach to process in #3. I'll try to add more details about the address in the answer.(Update it)

Comment: @ekolis You can also type ipconfig using cmd.exe in your remote machine(windows server) to check the IPV4 address, I don't mean the URL of your website...